# JQuery POST, get broken pipe error on rest service

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I have a collection of rest services, calling independently with postman they work fine.  I call getList with jquery works great.  When I do a POST to create a new object it works (as in the object gets created), but blows up getting the response which is the object that was just created with an id now.

```
$("#createEventSubmit").click(function(){
    createEvent();
});

function createEvent(){
    $.ajax({

        url: context + "/api/v1/organizer/event",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: formToJSON(),
        type: "POST",

        dataType : "json",

        success: function( json ) {
            console.log(json);
            setMessage("Event was created! " + json.id);
        },

        error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
            console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
            console.log( "Status: " + status );
            console.dir( xhr );
            setMessage("Sorry, your event was not created, please check your inputs.","ERROR");
        },

        complete: function( xhr, status ) {
            console.log( "Status: " + status );
        }
    });
}
```

Nothing happens visually and nothing gets put to the console.  The error on the app server is this:

```
18:17:47,193 INFO  [com.herdcat.web.api.v1.orgnaizer.event.OrganizerEvent] (default task-48) New Event Created: 60947792-0076-42d6-91d2-3d4144a40f5a
18:17:47,195 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-48) UT005023: Exception handling request to /hc/api/v1/organizer/event: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: Response is committed, can't handle exception
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.cleanup(AdviceFilter.java:196) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```

The weird thing is the GET jquery is set up exactly the same.  Pretty green to jquery so any advice is good advice for me.  AND the object does get created, it just can't seem to handle response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If nothing ever gets printed in the console, you either have errors, the function never runs, or the page reloads without you noticing.

Comment: @adeneo thanks, I believe the page is reloading.  I don't understand why it is, the form has no action and the button isn't a submit.  Does a page always refresh when you hit a button?  Do i need to force it to stop somehow?  Thanks again.

Comment: a `<button>` element has a default type of submit, and will always submit the form, and leaving out the action just makes it reload the same page!

Comment: ah well, there is my problem, thank you.  I guess, i really don't even need a form element.  what is the standard for submitting an ajax 'form', no <form>, button outside a form?, block the button? etc...

Comment: The standard is usually using a form as a fallback, and then listening for the form submit event, not the button click event, and then using `preventDefault` to make sure the form doesn't submit.

Comment: @adeneo great info, much appreciated.